# Google Analytics - Download clicks tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

I'm trying to track download clicks with Google Analytics but nothing shows up in my statistics. (I've waited 4 days) This is my code:

HTML:

```
 <a onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview ('/download/version/black');" href="http://www.example.com/example.zip"  target="_blank">link text</a>
```

Google Analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Why is it not working?
Thanks.
Uli

Comment: Just so we're clear, you're not actually using example.com and UA-11111111-1 right?

Comment: you shouldn't use `javascript:` inside onclick. Onclick value is already supposed to be javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GA events for this.

Check the docs for the `_trackEvent` method.

Comment: To track conversion rates and goals in GA I'll need to use _trackEvent too, right? Is this the right way to use it?: `<a href="bundle.zip" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Bundle', 'Premium']);">Premium Bundle</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to push your tracking events to the globally available array:

```
<a onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/download/version/black']);" href="http://www.example.com/example.zip"  target="_blank">link text</a>
```

I think you are mixing two versions of the tracking API together..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you're loading the async GA but trying to run the old urchin API.

```
<a href="foo.zip" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', this.href]);">download</a>
```

should work just fine